# Google Analytics 4 or Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

How can I tell what version of google analytics am I using? I was given access to GA (never used it before), and I need to know if it's GA4 or UA. Is there a way to tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have "Edit" access, you can simply navigate to the admin panel, then click on "Property Settings" in the middle column. If you see a tracking code which starts with "UA-" this means it's a Universal Analytics tracking code/property. If the tracking code starts with "G-" this means it is a GA4 (Google Analytics 4) tracking code/property.